# I don't have permissions to extract a theme to usr/share/docky/themes?

Tags: permissions, docky

I don't appear to have permissions to extract a theme to `usr/share/docky/themes` and I cant copy the extracted folder across when it is extracted.

I am using Lubuntu 12.04

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. Try this : `gksu nautilus` enter your password and extract your file. Enjoy Ubuntu!

Comment: thanks for your reply but when it still wont extract im just getting "Extraction not performed

You don't have the right permissions to extract archives in the folder "file:///usr/share/docky/themes"

Answer (score 5):

First extract the theme to your /home folder. Possibly a new folder will be created. (the theme folder)

Of course the permissions of /usr/share/ belongs to root. You can open a terminal and copy the entire folder (with the theme) with root privileges.

```
sudo cp -R /home/path/to/dir/theme/ /usr/share/docky/themes/
```

The -R means recursively , so the whole folder with the theme will be copied in /docky/themes/

Good Luck.

Comment: hi there trying to get to grips with it, terminal commands still mess with my head... my file is located in my downloads folder so is it home/downloads/darkglass

Comment: sudo cp -R ~/Downloads/darkglass /usr/share/docky/themes

Comment: I typed "sudo cp -R ~/home/paul/Downloads/DarkGlass /usr/share/docky/themes" and got "cp: cannot stat `/home/paul/home/paul/Downloads/DarkGlass': No such file or directory" in return

Comment: aha.. sudo pcmanfm then move it... so obvious

Comment: infact i never realised that you can open folder as root from the tools menu on pcmanfm.... simplest things eh?